# Julia Multi-Threading

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am currently using multi-threading in the following way in Julia:

```
Qx_values=(-0.6:0.05:0.6)`

Qy_values=(-0.6:0.05:0.6)

min_energy_values=zeros(length(Qx_values),length(Qy_values))

for i in axes (Qx_values,1)

Threads.@threads for j in axes (Qy_values,1)
         
               #for loop content

                end

end
```

However, I want to find a suitable way to join this together such that over a single for-loop that can speed the code up much more than the above

I have tried to use CartesianIndicies. However, I am unsure how to effectively use it to speed the code up. The result I have seems to work but for minimal speed up.

```
Threads.@threads for (i,j) in Tuple.(CartesianIndices((length(Qx_values),length(Qy_values)))

#for loop content

end
```

Is there a more suitable way to code this sort of case?

Comment: If you have already multithreaded the inner loop, you have already squeezed what you can from your cpu, it's not that multithreading the outer loop you can get much better ..

Comment: Another possible way to write the loop `for (i,j) in vec(collect(Iterators.product(1:length(Qx_values), 1:length(Qy_values))))`. Yet the @threads is polling jobs (the default option for `Thread.@threads` is `:dynamic`) so if `length(Qx_values)` is much greater than the number of threads it is enough to loop over only one dimension.

Comment: Say the length of Qx and Qy are both 25 each and I have 100 threads. Then changing to a single for loop with multithreading would speed this up, correct?

Comment: So what you are trying to do is a [collapse clause](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.2/openmpsu30.html) in OpenMP terms